# データセットをバッチ処理したいが、、、

Tags: python, python3, 深層学習, ipython

30万次元の要素をもつデータセット(data)を分析したいのですが、各バッチごとの要素をfor文でインスタンスに格納するときのコードを描こうと思ったら通りません。i番目のバッチが持つ1200個の要素をnew[i]に格納したいのですが、、分かりません。以下のようにしました。

```
for i in range(250):
    new = []
    new[i] = data[4000*i+1 : 300000*(i+1)/250]
```

Answer (score 2):

現状では`new[i]`の時に初期化ができていないので`list assignment index out of range`というエラーになります。問題点は多いですが、取り敢えず以下のようなコードから始めてみたらどうでしょうか。

```
new = []
for i in range(250):
    new.append(data[1200*i : 1200*(i+1)])
```